# Disabling and enabling Page Scrolling (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am using the following code to build the PageViewController. 
My question is how can I disable or enable the page scrolling in my "Front" and "Back" viewController?

```
class PageController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var pages = [UIViewController]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    let page1: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Front")
    let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Back")

    pages.append(page1)
    pages.append(page2)

    setViewControllers([page1], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
    let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)
    return pages[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
    let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)
    return pages[nextIndex]
}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return pages.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var pages = [UIViewController]()
var pageContollerEnabled = true
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    if let viewController = createViewController("Front") {
        pages.append(viewController)
        viewController.tag = pages.count
        setViewControllers([viewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    if let viewController = createViewController("Back") {
        pages.append(viewController)
        viewController.tag = pages.count
    }

}

private func createViewController (identifier:String) -> ViewController? {
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier)
    if let viewController = viewController as? ViewController{
        viewController.pageViewController = self
        return viewController
    }
    return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if (pageContollerEnabled) {
        let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
        let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)
        if let previousViewController = pages[previousIndex] as? ViewController {
            if previousViewController.tag <= currentIndex {
                return pages[previousIndex]
            }
        }
    }
    return nil

}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if (pageContollerEnabled) {
        let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
        let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)
        if let nextViewController = pages[nextIndex] as? ViewController {
            if nextViewController.tag > currentIndex {
                return pages[nextIndex]
            }
        }
    }
    return nil

}


func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return pages.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}
}
```

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var pageViewController: PageViewController?

@IBAction func valueChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
    NSLog("Swith \(sender.on)")
    if let pageViewController = self.pageViewController {
        pageViewController.pageContollerEnabled = sender.on
    }
}   
}
```

> Main.storyboard

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="10117" systemVersion="15G31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="uMa-bV-FKZ">
<dependencies>
    <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="10085"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--Page View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="v41-UK-OxZ">
        <objects>
            <pageViewController autoresizesArchivedViewToFullSize="NO" transitionStyle="pageCurl" navigationOrientation="horizontal" spineLocation="min" id="uMa-bV-FKZ" customClass="PageViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_38980301" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController"/>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iKI-ej-UeC" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="424" y="356"/>
    </scene>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="rJU-DG-wgp">
        <objects>
            <viewController storyboardIdentifier="Front" useStoryboardIdentifierAsRestorationIdentifier="YES" id="xxX-RS-ZVZ" customClass="ViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_38980301" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="c8s-ud-821"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="JbG-NZ-eP5"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="rpm-D4-Tqn">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Front" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="MhC-PV-UBQ">
                            <rect key="frame" x="280" y="289" width="41" height="21"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                            <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                        <switch opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" verticalHuggingPriority="750" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" on="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="OaO-rT-mzv">
                            <rect key="frame" x="276" y="318" width="51" height="31"/>
                            <connections>
                                <action selector="valueChanged:" destination="xxX-RS-ZVZ" eventType="valueChanged" id="lUx-Cz-lJl"/>
                            </connections>
                        </switch>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="OaO-rT-mzv" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="MhC-PV-UBQ" secondAttribute="centerX" id="3U1-6y-cKV"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="MhC-PV-UBQ" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="rpm-D4-Tqn" secondAttribute="centerY" id="Bge-Ih-jR4"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="OaO-rT-mzv" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="MhC-PV-UBQ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="gTI-yU-mMe"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="MhC-PV-UBQ" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="rpm-D4-Tqn" secondAttribute="centerX" id="rJq-ad-5Ur"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="vQZ-k5-cBN" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="1078" y="356"/>
    </scene>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="636-Kw-KXs">
        <objects>
            <viewController storyboardIdentifier="Back" useStoryboardIdentifierAsRestorationIdentifier="YES" id="ICA-gO-3et" customClass="ViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_38980301" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="z7N-pb-J88"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wrb-EO-FlO"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="XiV-R4-9yG">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Back" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="JHB-ln-wGN">
                            <rect key="frame" x="281" y="289" width="38" height="21"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                            <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                        <switch opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" verticalHuggingPriority="750" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" on="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="MLj-y6-3eJ">
                            <rect key="frame" x="276" y="318" width="51" height="31"/>
                            <connections>
                                <action selector="valueChanged:" destination="ICA-gO-3et" eventType="valueChanged" id="ae6-jj-HHQ"/>
                            </connections>
                        </switch>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="JHB-ln-wGN" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="MLj-y6-3eJ" secondAttribute="centerX" id="KOk-1n-svY"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="JHB-ln-wGN" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="XiV-R4-9yG" secondAttribute="centerY" id="LQa-xT-oAG"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="MLj-y6-3eJ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="JHB-ln-wGN" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="WzC-ed-F8F"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="JHB-ln-wGN" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="XiV-R4-9yG" secondAttribute="centerX" id="tte-Vg-fy5"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Q0j-fT-PZ9" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="1740" y="356"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
</document>
```